# How do I make sure my glyph is at the top (visual studio extension)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, glyph

I'm currently working on a visual studio extension with a simple glyph (it's an image that capture a click event and show a dialog window) and my glyph provider look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IGlyphFactoryProvider))]
[Name("MutationCodeHighlightGlyph")]
[Order(After = "VsTextMarker")]
[ContentType("code")]
[TagType(typeof(MutationCodeHighlightTag))]
public class MutationCodeHighlightGlyphFactoryProvider : IGlyphFactoryProvider
{
    public IGlyphFactory GetGlyphFactory(IWpfTextView view, IWpfTextViewMargin margin)
    {
        return new MutationCodeHighlightGlyphFactory();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have the `[Order(After = "VsTextMarker")]` and I can see the glyph and click on it when debugging. But later on when I install it on my regular visual studio I can only see it but not click. So it feels like something is catching my click event and I guess it's resharper after reading this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a83a2e18-090f-49c7-98fb-33d687f936d0/how-to-set-iglyphfactoryprovider-order?forum=vsx

He talks about a special Resharper canvas that may capture the events(but sadly doesn't say the name of it). But there must be a workaround this? It feels a bit weird that an extension can create it's own canvas and grab all events so all other third party extensions fail.

Edit: Just tried and disabled resharper and now it works fine.. so somehow resharper steal all click events.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I didn't actually solve it - I just found the root problem. I still think it's strange that another plugin can steal the whole canvas layer and put itself above all the others. 

And right now my plugin won't work if you install resharper so it would be nice to find a solution for it.

Comment: I think the issue could be more related to the third party extension Resharper and i suggest you could contact with them to reflect this issue.